# ObservableCollection don't Binding in CodeBehind

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

ObservableCollection don't Binding
Hello guys,

I need help in one question of ObservableCollection using in Xamarin Forms.
I need build one "Custom ListView" for TabIndex works correctly in my screen.
For this i create in code behind:
 - ScrollView
 - Label
 - Entry

Screen rendering is works ok, only my problem is on binding in one ObservableCollection.

I my tests one property single string using OnPropertyChanged works correctly, but using ObservableCollection dont works. I tried using CollectionChanged but withour success.

Someone having same problem? Exist solution for this?

**ViewModel:**

```
    private ObservableCollection<RawData> rawDataList;
    public ObservableCollection<RawData> RawDataList
    {
        get { return rawDataList; }
        set { rawDataList = value; OnPropertyChanged("RawDataList"); }
    }
```

**Code Behind**

```
    private void BuildRawDataTemplate()
    {
        var grid = BuildGrid();

        #region Templates
        grid.Children.Add(BuildScheduleHeaderTitleTemplate(), 0, 0); // Posição: Coluna: 0 | Linha: 0
        grid.Children.Add(BuildScheduleDetailsSubtitleTemplate("Dados Brutos"), 0, 1); // Posição: Coluna: 0 | Linha: 1
        #endregion

        #region RawData
        var scrollView = BuildScrollView();
        var stackLayout = BuildStackLayout("DefaultLight", 10, StackOrientation.Vertical, null, LayoutOptions.Center);

        rawDataCount = scheduleViewModel.RawDataList.Count();
        foreach (var item in scheduleViewModel.RawDataList.Select((rawData, i) => new { i, rawData }))
        {
            stackLayout.Children.Add(GenerateLabel(item.rawData.Identification));

            if (item.rawData.InfoTypeId == (int)InfoType.Equipment)
                stackLayout.Children.Add(GenerateEquipmentsPicker(item.rawData, item.i, item.i == 0, rawDataCount == (item.i + 1)));
            else
                stackLayout.Children.Add(GenerateEntry(item.rawData, item.i, item.i == 0, rawDataCount == (item.i + 1)));
        }
        scrollView.Content = stackLayout;

        grid.Children.Add(scrollView, 0, 2); // Posição: Coluna: 0 | Linha: 2
        #endregion

        #region Buttons
        var stackLayoutFooterButtons = BuildStackLayout(string.Empty, null, StackOrientation.Horizontal, LayoutOptions.End, null);
        stackLayoutFooterButtons.Children.Add(GeneratePrimaryButton("RESULTADOS", scheduleViewModel.VisibleResultCommand, rawDataCount++, scheduleViewModel.SelectedSampleBase.Finished));
        stackLayoutFooterButtons.Children.Add(GeneratePrimaryButton("CALCULAR", scheduleViewModel.CalculateRawDataCommand, rawDataCount++, !scheduleViewModel.SelectedSampleBase.Synced));
        stackLayoutFooterButtons.Children.Add(GeneratePrimaryButton("SALVAR", scheduleViewModel.SaveRawDataCommand, rawDataCount++, !scheduleViewModel.SelectedSampleBase.Synced));

        grid.Children.Add(stackLayoutFooterButtons, 0, 3); // Posição: Coluna: 0 | Linha: 3
        #endregion

        Content = grid;

        SetFocusOnFirstEntry();
    }

    private Entry GenerateEntry(RawData rawData, int tabIndex, bool firstElement = false, bool hasNextTabIndex = false)
    {
        var entry = new Entry();
        entry.TabIndex = tabIndex;

        entry.Text = rawData.DisplayValue;
        entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, nameof(rawData.DisplayValue), BindingMode.TwoWay);

        entry.StyleId = $"RawDataDynamicEntry_{tabIndex}";
        entry.IsTabStop = true;
        entry.IsEnabled = rawData.NotSynced;

        if (rawData.InfoTypeId == (int)InfoType.Integer)
            entry.Behaviors.Add(new NumericValidationBehavior());

        if (firstElement)
            entry.Focus();

        // Temp
        var focusOnReturnBehavior = new FocusOnReturnBehavior();
        focusOnReturnBehavior.HasNextTabIndex = hasNextTabIndex;
        entry.Behaviors.Add(focusOnReturnBehavior);

        return entry;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resolve my problem i using:

**Code-Behind**

```
    #region Events Changed
    private void EntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var entryChanged = (Entry)sender;
        selectedRawData.DisplayValue = entryChanged.Text;
    }
    private void PickerSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var pickerChanged = (Picker)sender;
        selectedRawData.DisplayValue = selectedItem.Identification;
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

I am little confused by the question. But I believe you have problem adding the entries to listview. Your Observable collection data is not getting populated in Listview.

I wrote a post on creating multiselect listview. You just see how I'm creating a listview and binding the contents of observable collection to it.

Please see here: https://androidwithashray.blogspot.com/2018/03/multiselect-list-view-using-xamarin.html

Please note for listview, you don't need scrollview as listview auto scrolls if the contents are more to fit inside the screen.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Nice Post! Thank you for help me. I need to use "custom listview" for using tab controls in UWP. This don't works in listview when used with StackLayout and Entry. Tab set focus only first StackLayout. Thats why rendered screen in code-behind.

Comment: Nice to know it helped :-) Can you please up vote for the my answer.

Comment: Ashray P. Shetty, I got used to TextChanged. Tks for you help!